# nfcpy read text data instead of serial number

Tags: python, nfc

I have the following python code that uses nfcpy to print serial number everytime a rfid card is touched on the scanner.

It works great, but I'm not sure how I can read other information specially custom text data that I have put on the card.

Does anyone know how text data can be read using the code below?

```
from nfc import ContactlessFrontend
import time

def connected(tag):
    ident = ''.join('{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in tag.identifier)
    print(ident)
    return False

clf = ContactlessFrontend('usb')
while True:
    clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': connected})
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Did you put your custom text data on using a NFC standard like Ndef? or did you write it using your own format to the low level API's for your specific make and model of a NFC Tag?

Comment: @Andrew I wrote the data to the card using an App on my phone call NFC tools. When i scan the card with my phone or any other phone it shows the text data.

Comment: or is there a way to possibly print the nfc tag type? basically i want to be able to ignore mobile tags and just scan cards that i have

Answer (score 0):

So NFC tools writes Ndef Data to Nfc Tags

From https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/get-started.html

> An NFC Forum Tag can store NFC Data Exchange Format (NDEF) Records in
> a specifically formatted memory region. NDEF data is found
> automatically and wrapped into an NDEF object accessible through the
> tag.ndef attribute. When NDEF data is not present the attribute is
> simply None.

```
 assert tag.ndef is not None
 for record in tag.ndef.records:
     print(record)
```

> NDEF Uri Record ID '' Resource 'http://nfcpy.org'

Etc.

Comment: How would integrate that into my existing code above? i tried putting it into the connected function but does not work